# What effect was used on these Crysis 2 SFX?

Tags: sfx, video-games, effect

I am curious to know what effect was used on these Crysis 2 sound effects. They sound...gritty. Do you have any idea ?

https://soundcloud.com/flopod-1/crysis-2/s-YJlYz

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for opinions, It sounds like the source sound is made up of;

A rocky surface(gritty, ha) being hit with a heavy object, with rocks being dislodged, crumbling and falling.

There's also a wooden stick kind of whacking sound. Maybe the crumbling rocks are hitting wooden floor. Sounds more like they're hitting logs or Bamboo though.

As for the effects;

It sounds like there's a Low Pass, maybe notch filter, with high resonance. Or maybe it's just been boosted in the lower mid range to get that 'middy' effect.

It sounds slightly 'fat' like it's gone through some amplifier distortion.

Probably a couple of compressors fast/slow.

One of my ears is bad at the moment, so I have hardly any perception of stereo effects, but this is where I'd start if I were to try and recreate this sound.

Comment: I'm curious as to what this sound effect was used for in the game?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It's the main character walking with his nanosuit and weapons. We hear the sound from his perspective, inside his helmet.

Comment: ah ok. The filtering is because he has a helmet on then.